# Weird behaviour when comparing dates

Tags: sas

I want to compare 2 date constants by:

```
data _null_;
    %put checking if &period_bop1Yend is greater than &latest_date;
    if "&period_bop1Yend"d > "&latest_date"d then do;
        %put "IF entered";
        %let period_bop1Yend = &latest_date;
    end;
run;
%put &period_bop1Yend;
```

But why do I get "IF entered" message in log when **&period_bop1Yend** = '31DEC2013' and **&latest_date** = '31AUG2014' - it is clearly seen that the result of camparison is false???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'weird behaviour' in your date comparison, it's correct. This issue is that you're mixing macro and datastep incorrectly...

```
data _null_;
    put "checking if &period_bop1Yend is greater than &latest_date" ;
    if "&period_bop1Yend"d > "&latest_date"d then do;
        put "IF entered";
        call symput('period_bop1Yend',"&latest_date"d) ;
    end;
run;
%put &period_bop1Yend;
```

But why not do it far more simply...

```
%LET PERIOD_BOP1YEND = %SYSFUNC(max("&PERIOD_BOP1YEND"d,"&LATEST_DATE"d),date9.) ;
```

Comment: A perfect explanation and solution!